# Thread 'tokio-runtime-worker' panicked at 'Integer overflow when casting to u64'

Tags: substrate-node-template, bug, tokio

I am running substrate based solo chain using AURA and GRANDPA. I have upgraded the runtime to use polkadot v0.9.27 branch and it was working fine for some days. now suddenly my nodes are getting this error message:

```
   0: sp_panic_handler::set::{{closure}}
   1: std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook
             at rustc/fe5b13d681f25ee6474be29d748c65adcd91f69e/library/std/src/panicking.rs:702:17
   2: std::panicking::begin_panic_handler::{{closure}}
             at rustc/fe5b13d681f25ee6474be29d748c65adcd91f69e/library/std/src/panicking.rs:586:13
   3: std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_end_short_backtrace
             at rustc/fe5b13d681f25ee6474be29d748c65adcd91f69e/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:138:18
   4: rust_begin_unwind
             at rustc/fe5b13d681f25ee6474be29d748c65adcd91f69e/library/std/src/panicking.rs:584:5
   5: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at rustc/fe5b13d681f25ee6474be29d748c65adcd91f69e/library/core/src/panicking.rs:143:14
   6: <core::future::from_generator::GenFuture<T> as core::future::future::Future>::poll
   7: <futures_util::future::future::map::Map<Fut,F> as core::future::future::Future>::poll
   8: <sc_service::task_manager::prometheus_future::PrometheusFuture<T> as core::future::future::Future>::poll
   9: <futures_util::future::select::Select<A,B> as core::future::future::Future>::poll
  10: <core::future::from_generator::GenFuture<T> as core::future::future::Future>::poll
  11: tokio::loom::std::unsafe_cell::UnsafeCell<T>::with_mut
  12: tokio::runtime::task::core::CoreStage<T>::poll
  13: tokio::runtime::task::harness::poll_future
  14: tokio::runtime::task::harness::Harness<T,S>::poll
  15: std::thread::local::LocalKey<T>::with
  16: tokio::runtime::thread_pool::worker::Context::run_task
  17: tokio::runtime::thread_pool::worker::Context::run
  18: tokio::macros::scoped_tls::ScopedKey<T>::set
  19: tokio::runtime::thread_pool::worker::run
  20: <tokio::runtime::blocking::task::BlockingTask<T> as core::future::future::Future>::poll
  21: tokio::runtime::task::harness::Harness<T,S>::poll
  22: tokio::runtime::blocking::pool::Inner::run
  23: std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace
  24: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once{{vtable.shim}}
  25: <alloc::boxed::Box<F,A> as core::ops::function::FnOnce<Args>>::call_once
             at rustc/fe5b13d681f25ee6474be29d748c65adcd91f69e/library/alloc/src/boxed.rs:1861:9
      <alloc::boxed::Box<F,A> as core::ops::function::FnOnce<Args>>::call_once
             at rustc/fe5b13d681f25ee6474be29d748c65adcd91f69e/library/alloc/src/boxed.rs:1861:9
      std::sys::unix::thread::Thread::new::thread_start
             at rustc/fe5b13d681f25ee6474be29d748c65adcd91f69e/library/std/src/sys/unix/thread.rs:108:17
  26: <unknown>
  27: __clone


Thread 'tokio-runtime-worker' panicked at 'Integer overflow when casting to u64', /home/user/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/primitive-types-0.10.1/src/lib.rs:38
```

How can I fix this bug?

Answer (score 1):

The path `github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/primitive-types-0.10.1/src/lib.rs:38` seems to link to U256 type.

You probably triggered this error: https://github.com/paritytech/parity-common/blob/1d3a3d5138403bbf07d42978b29d8ac7d3fff53b/uint/src/uint.rs#L655

So I guess some code is using a U256 and is calling `as_u64` on a value which overflows u64 type.

Try using `TryFrom` trait instead of `as_u64` in your code maybe or look where this could triggered I guess.